# How to properly <ins>-markup a <dl><dt><dd>?

Tags: html, css

I am using `<ins>` and `<del>` to markup editorial changes in a document. To make them better readable they are colored in some green and red in addition to `<u>` and `<s>`. It all works fine except for the dl-dd-dt lists. There, I use an `<ins>` all around, but the green color is not preserved neither for the `<dt>` nor the `<dd>`.

I am aware that I can add another `<ins>` to each `<dt>` and `<dd>`.  But I would, if possible, prefer a more principled approach: After all, the *entire* text including its indentation should be added and not only the elements, so it would be semantically more accurate to have a single enclosing `<ins>`.

(I am using Firefox 39.0, should this matter)

```css
ins {
  background: #e4ffe4
}
del {
  background: #ffd0d0
}
```

```html
<INS>
          Preamble, green
    <DL>
    <DT>dt: underlined but not green
    <DD>dd: underlined but not green
    
    <DT><INS>dt-with-ins, green</INS>
<DD>
  <INS>dd-with-ins, green</INS>

  </DL>
  </INS>

  <HR>
  <A href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer">Validated HTML</A>
```

Comment: I just did by removing it from your question.

Comment: "I am using Firefox 39.0, should this matter" Well, it shouldn't, because the browser that matters is the user's, not the developers.

Comment: Will do. For some reason my tabs use "needs answer" as default.

Comment: @PeeHaa: new-nav ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go.  Just add an `ins dl` style.

```css
ins, ins dl {
  background: #e4ffe4
}
del {
  background: #ffd0d0
}
```

```html
<INS>
          Preamble, green
    <DL>
    <DT>dt: underlined but not green
    <DD>dd: underlined but not green
    
    <DT><INS>dt-with-ins, green</INS>
<DD>
  <INS>dd-with-ins, green</INS>

  </DL>
  </INS>

  <HR>
  <A href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer">Validated HTML</A>
```

Comment: Yes, instead of setting the style on the BACKGROUND you would set it on the COLOR.

Comment: Oh, okay, I get it.  Yes, you would have to wrap the INS tags around the individual elements instead of the whole list.

Comment: @false I think this is what you want. Take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/LzbeoLd2/

Comment: It's for the one you have marked as "underlined but not green".  The code should be clear.  Do you have a question?

Comment: And what is it that you wish to have?

Comment: The example shows you how to have just an underline or underline with green.  What else do you need?

Comment: What I wanted is only a green background for the text implicitely with `<ins>`  but not on the left and right side which is quite irritating. Anyway, if this is not possible, so be it.

Comment: Yes, my example does that.  Is there a problem?

Comment: Did you look at the jsfiddle I linked to? Here it is again: https://jsfiddle.net/LzbeoLd2/

Comment: Yes I did. And it does not answer what I am after: That is, your original answer has too much filled with green. And I just consider whether or not it is possible to reduce it - without changing the markup - only via CSS. If you have a maximal width for text, it looks very odd if you have this giant green bar.

Comment: To get it to work how you want, you need to fix the markup.  It was bad in your original question.  So you cannot have both.  You can have bad markup and big green boxes or you can fix the markup and have small green boxes but you CANNOT have bad markup and small green boxes.  Without the proper closing tags there is just no way for the green box to know where to end.

Comment: Semantically, I want to say; Insert that entire dl-list. To express this, my markup seems ok.

Comment: And that's fine, but since they are block elements then the green will extend the full width of the container.  But regardless, you're still missing the closing tags so your markup is not okay as it was.

Comment: Your other option would be to add SPAN wrappers to your DTs and DDs and then style the SPANs.

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle to demonstrate the use of SPAN tags.  And since they are appropriate for styling text, you are still semantically correct: https://jsfiddle.net/LzbeoLd2/2/

Answer (score 6):

`ins` elements are inline by default. Try making them `block` or `inline-block`

```css
ins {
  background: #e4ffe4;
  text-decoration: underline;
  display: inline-block;
}
del {
  background: #ffd0d0;
}
```

```html
<ins>
  Preamble, green
  <dl>
    <dt>dt: underlined and green</dt>
    <dd>dd: underlined and green</dd>
    <dt><ins>dt-with-ins, green</ins></dt>
    <dd><ins>dd-with-ins, green</ins></dd>
  </dl>
</ins>
<hr />
<a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer">Validated HTML</a>
```

Comment: Can't that change the appearance of the page? altering the display types like that? (Of course when considering the content is unknown and not limited DD/DT/DL...)

Comment: That's possible, but probably it won't affect much.

Comment: Is it actually possibe that only the text gets green and not the space right and left of it?

Comment: @false I don't think so, unless you wrap the text inside inline elements ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jfg1nsmu/)).

Answer (score 2):

@false, I agree with Lance about using the span elements and embedding them in the ins element. I think this code should create the look you desire.

```css
ins, ins span { 
    background: #e4ffe4;
} 
del { 
    background: #ffd0d0;
}
```

```html
<ins>Preamble, green
<dl>
    <dt>dt: underlined but not green</dt>
    <dd>dd: underlined but not green</dd>
    <dt><span>dt-with-ins, green</span></dt>
    <dd><span>dd-with-ins, green</span></dd>
</dl>
</ins>
```

Let me know if this is the look you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the (un-recommended...) catch-all selector (*) as a catch-all for descendents:

```css
ins, ins * { /* <- Catch all! */
  background: #e4ffe4
}
del, del * { /* <- Catch all! */
  background: #ffd0d0
}
```

```html
<INS>
          Preamble, green
    <DL>
    <DT>dt: underlined but not green
    <DD>dd: underlined but not green
    
    <DT><INS>dt-with-ins, green</INS>
<DD>
  <INS>dd-with-ins, green</INS>

  </DL>
  </INS>

  <HR>
  <A href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer">Validated HTML</A>
```